# How to pass data from child custom element back to parent element from where it is called in Polymer 2

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

i have this custom element in polymer below

```
 <parent-element> 
     <child-element myData="{{data}}"> </child-element>   <!--modifies the data-->
     <!-- Want to pass updated data to child-element-2-->

     <child-element-2> </child-element-2> 
 </parent-element>
```

Let me know how to pass the updated data to 2nd child element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data-binding is the way to go here.
You should be using a dash on the attribute while in the properties a camelCase. You can read about this in the Polymer documentation [Property name to attribute name mapping](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties).

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <my-child-one data="{{data}}"></my-child-one>
    <my-child-two add-data="[[data]]"></my-child-two>
  </template>
  <script>
   Polymer({
     is: 'my-element',

       properties: {

         data: {
          type: String,
       },
   });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Also do not forget to set notify to true on the property inside the my-child-one Element.

Comment: Can you send my modification to your answer back to me, renfeng.cn@gmail.com Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find your modification anymore. But I also did not see any significant improvements. It was rather more confusing as it took a part the Polymer syntax.

Comment: It's okay. May be it was deleted once your answer was accepted - the modifications were 1) to update your link to Polymer 2 as this was not a question on Polymer 1; 2) to match the sample code with that was provided in the question, along with mandatory update to child element; 3) grammar and syntax